# How can I have different type of events in Fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony, fullcalendar

I'm trying to have two sort of events in full calendar.

One of them is clickable and open a popup when I click on them.

The others one don't take care if I click on them.

I'm using `Fullcalendar` with `Symfony` : https://github.com/adesigns/calendar-bundle

Anybody know how to do that?

EDIT:

In my calendar-settings.js:

```
$('#calendar-holder').fullCalendar({


    select: function (start, end, jsEvent, view) {
        alert("test");
    }),
    eventSources: [
        {
          url: Routing.generate('fullcalendar_loader'),
          type: 'POST',
          data: {},
          error: function () {},
       },
    ]
```

Then in my CalendarEventListener I have:

```
class CalendarEventListener {

    private $entityManager;

public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager) {
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
}
 public function loadEvents(CalendarEvent $calendarEvent) {      
    $eventEntity = new EventEntity('firstEvent', new DateTime(), new DateTime());
    $calendarEvent->addEvent($eventEntity);
    $eventEntity = new EventEntity('secondEvent', new DateTime(), new DateTime());
    $calendarEvent->addEvent($eventEntity);
 }
```

Comment: I edited my post, I use fullcalendars bundle with symfony: https://github.com/adesigns/calendar-bundle

Comment: Please show your event handling code in plugin options object. Also event objects to know what difference is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way may be to have a property 'clickable' or something in the event object set to true/false, and then upon [eventClick](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/eventClick/) only proceed where it is clickable = true?

```
eventClick: function (event, jsEvent, view) {
    if (event.clickable === false) { return; }
    // Else, carry on
}
```

Comment: oh yes, so I can do what I want and more! Thanls!!